# Resolution of Android phone messes up loading program

Tags: java, android

I was running my simple 3x3 grid-type game application on Android Studio with the Nexus emulator and everything was working fine. However, when I plugged in my LG G3 to my computer, some of the buttons stacked on top of each other, making a 2x3 grid instead of the 3x3 I need. Does anyone know a solution to having the same looking program run on my phone? Thanks for any an all help.

The layout I am using is relative layout.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_gravity="top|right"
android:background="#ff65b4ff"
android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
android:id="@+id/activity_game">

<Button
    android:layout_width="80dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:text="@string/back"
    android:layout_gravity="top|right"
    android:id="@+id/back_button"/>


<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/show_unknown_distance_button"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="432dp"
    android:gravity="center">
<Button
    android:layout_width="70dp"
    android:layout_height="70dp"
    android:id="@+id/top_center_button"
    android:layout_margin="5dp"/>


<Button
    android:layout_width="70dp"
    android:layout_height="70dp"
    android:id="@+id/center_button"
    android:layout_below="@+id/top_center_button"
    android:layout_margin="5dp"/>
<Button
    android:layout_width="70dp"
    android:layout_height="70dp"
    android:id="@+id/bottom_center_button"
    android:layout_below="@+id/center_button"
    android:layout_margin="5dp"/>
<Button
    android:layout_width="70dp"
    android:layout_height="70dp"
    android:id="@+id/top_right_button"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/top_center_button"
    android:layout_margin="5dp"/>
<Button
    android:layout_width="70dp"
    android:layout_height="70dp"
    android:id="@+id/right_button"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/center_button"
    android:layout_below="@+id/top_right_button"
    android:layout_margin="5dp"/>
<Button
    android:layout_width="70dp"
    android:layout_height="70dp"
    android:id="@+id/bottom_right_button"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/bottom_center_button"
    android:layout_below="@+id/right_button"
    android:layout_margin="5dp"/>
<Button
    android:layout_width="70dp"
    android:layout_height="70dp"
    android:id="@+id/top_left_button"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/top_center_button"
    android:layout_margin="5dp"/>
<Button
    android:layout_width="70dp"
    android:layout_height="70dp"
    android:id="@+id/left_button"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/center_button"
    android:layout_below="@+id/top_left_button"
    android:layout_margin="5dp"/>
<Button
    android:layout_width="70dp"
    android:layout_height="70dp"
    android:id="@+id/bottom_left_button"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/bottom_center_button"
    android:layout_below="@+id/right_button"
    android:layout_margin="5dp"/>


</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Please provide more information about the layout you are trying to get working.

Comment: Just uploaded xml file